# When dealing with WebServices in Android which approach would be better KSOAP2 or Android default HTTPClient

Tags: android, web-services, rest

As I am writing a Webservice client to deal with the webservices for my application in android, I am bit confused about the approaches among KSOAP2 and Android default HTTPCLient, Which one would be more relevant to use in Android

Suggestions Welcome.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's a SOAP webservice you are trying to consume then I would definitely use a SOAP client library such as KSOAP2.  If it's not a SOAP webservice, then I'd probably just use HTTPClient.

Answer (score 0):

KSOAP is *ok* however it has trouble de/serialising complex types. I burnt serious time with KSOAP and every time reverted back to building the soap packet and POSTing it.

KSOAP and KSOAP2 has patchy support.

From a performance POV, SAX parser is built into Android library and it is very fast.

[THIS](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/x-android/) is possibly the best article about it all.